# Typescript: Treating function parameter as a literal type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, literals

I'm trying to write a HOC to consume React context which by default can only be consumed with render props.

It works by rendering the `WrappedComponent` within a context Consumer and passes the context as the `key` prop which is provided during usage of the HOC.

The component is working fine and the types of the resulting component is correct but there is a type error in the implementation as `K` is used as a key but in typescript keys must be literal types. Is there a way to enforce that the generic is not only a `string` but a string literal?

```
import React from "react"

function getConsumer<C>(
  Context: React.Context<C> | React.Consumer<C>,
): React.Consumer<C> {
  return (Context as any).Consumer || Context
}

export const withContext = <C extends any, K extends string>(
  Context: React.Context<C> | React.Consumer<C>,
  key: K,
) => <P extends { [K /* Error here, K must be a literal type */]: C }>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
  type NewProps = Omit<P, K>

  return class WithContext extends React.Component<NewProps> {
    render() {
      const Consumer = getConsumer(Context)
      return (
        <Consumer>
          {context => (
            <WrappedComponent
              {...Object.assign({}, this.props, { [key || "context"]: context })}
            />
          )}
        </Consumer>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enforce that `K` is a literal type, but you could use a mapped type instead of a type with a computed property

```
P extends { [P in K ]: C }
```

or

```
P extends Record<K, C>
```